# Visual SourceSafe script starting out

Tags: scripting, label, visual-sourcesafe

I have never wrote a script before and I was asked today to make a Visual SourceSafe script that returns all of the labels that are stored.

I have 0 idea on how to start this as I have never wrote a script before. Can anybody point me in the right direction with this please?
Thanks!

Comment: "Visual SourceSafe" - Still? Really?  AAAaarrrghh!!!

Comment: @MitchWheat What? If it's something to do with it being shit its nothing to do with me ha I was just asked to make a script, I'm interning at a company. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [History command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/7174xsc2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of SourceSafe to get the history info of an item and extract the label info you need.

Here is a simple sample for you:

```
private void GetItem(VSSItem vssItem)
    {

            if (vssItem.Type == 0)  //Type == 0 means it's a project
            {
                bool bIncludeDeleted = false;
                IVSSItems vssItems = vssItem.get_Items(bIncludeDeleted);
                foreach (VSSItem vssitem in vssItems)
                {
                    GetItem(vssitem);

                    foreach (IVSSVersion vssVersion in vssitem.get_Versions(0))
                    {
                        string vssItemName = "";
                        if (vssVersion.VSSItem.Name == "")
                            vssItemName = vssitem.Spec;
                        else
                            vssItemName = vssVersion.VSSItem.Spec;

                        if (vssVersion.Action.IndexOf("Label") > -1 )
                        {
                            if (vssitem.Spec == vssVersion.VSSItem.Spec)
                            {

                                MessageBox.Show("Item " + vssItemName + " in " + "Version " + vssVersion.VersionNumber.ToString() + " With the lable:  " + vssVersion.Label);
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for that. How would I make the script return all labels?

Comment: I've added the sample script for your reference. Let me know how it works for you.